# Bonobo Git server on Azure Websites and Azure Storage

Tags: asp.net, git, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, bonobo

I'm using Bonobo Git Server. I want to host this application on Azure Website, but there is a disk limitation to ~10gb (Basic plan). This is not enough to host git repositories. I'm thinking if there is any way to use Azure Storage connected to my website to host those repositories?

Currently bonobo application uses local git .exe to perform appropriate processes with repositories. I have no idea how I can make this working with Azure Storage or if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get `git.exe` to work with azure storage without mounting it as a normal file system like in Azure Files which won't work in azure Web Apps anyway. You can upgrade to premium and get 500 GB though, so depending on your scenario, you may wanna look into that.